# How do you check for an error in an event in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

So I'm trying to make an error handler for events in discord.py, but all I found is the `on_command_error` handler, which only works for commands. 
Is there any error handler for events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an error handler for events in discord.py. The on_error event handler can be used to handle any errors that occur during the handling of an event. This event handler is triggered whenever an error occurs while an event is being processed, and it allows you to handle the error and take appropriate action. To use the on_error event handler, you can register it like any other event handler in discord.py. For example:

```
@client.event
async def on_error(event, *args, **kwargs):
    # Handle the error here
```

You can then use this event handler to handle any errors that occur during the handling of an event. This can be useful for logging errors, displaying error messages to users, or taking other appropriate action.

Comment: what type of arguments are passed in `*args` and `**kwargs`?